# Imaged windows 7 won't boot

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, migration, recovery

I have a physical windows7 system (HP) and am migrating the user to a new windows10 machine. I'd like to virtualize this machine as a backup. I clonezilla'd the drive and if it was windows 10 I'd be able to just boot it in my hypervisor environment. Being windows 7 it won't boot. I tried the startup repair and get "Unspecified changes to system configuration might have caused the problem." which makes sense. I can re-install the OS from a windows7 disk, but then it just moves everything to Windows.old which defeats the purpose of this move.

I've tried:

- `bootrec /fixmbr` (I don't think this does anything since it's a EFI install)
- `bootrec /fixboot`
- `bootrec /rebuildbcd`
- Interesting that `bootrec /scanos` returns 0 found installs
- I've done `chkdsk` and it's fine
- I have [the log from booting](https://pastebin.com/HKtLaiab) with `Boot Logging`.
- `Safe Mode with Command Prompt` hangs on `Loaded: \windows\system32\drivers\CLASSPNP.SYS` and reboots to recovery
- I even got crazy since I have snapshots of this VM and did a separate clean install and ran this from the recovery ISO:

  - `robocopy /mir clean_install:\windows\system32\drivers broken_vm:\windows\system32\drivers`
  - `robocopy /mir clean_install:\windows broken_vm:\windows`
  - `robocopy /mir clean_install:\boot broken_vm:\boot`
- I also booted the windows ISO recovery and gave it a qemu driver ISO:

  - `for /r %d in (*.inf) do drvload %d`
  - `for /r %d in (*.inf) do c:\windows\pnputil -i -a %d`
  - `for /r %d in (*.inf) do copy %d C:\windows\system32\drivers`

and none of those fixed it (which I guess makes sense, I didn't think it would). I also tried the `bootrec` commands and `Startup Repiar` between the `robocopy`s.

I can copy the user's Docs/Downloads/Desktop/etc, but if there's a program that's installed that I miss, then they'd be stuck until I could find an installer and fix it.

**Edits:**

I used clonezilla to create an image (as a backup), then used clonezilla to restore the image to the VM's disk.

I am using proxmox (quemu) as my hypervisor. I am using UEFI. I am able to reinstall windows 7 over this VM using UEFI and it works fine, just that everything gets moved to Windows.old.

I don't know for sure if it was physically UEFI, but if I try to boot BIOS it seems to stop at `Booting from Hard Disk` but if I boot with UEFI I at least get the windows logo. Also the disk is gpt, which I feel like implies UEFI; fdisk from linux shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1 TiB, 1099511627776 bytes, 2147483648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2      206848     468991     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3      468992 1918310399 1917841408 914.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1918310400 1953523711   35213312  16.8G Microsoft basic data
```

I wonder if I could get back to the physical machine, if I could run sysprep to make a more compatible image; I didn't want to modify the original physical, but I guess since I have an image of it, I could restore that image back after capturing the sysprep version.

Comment: Which hypervisor? How is the VM defined? If you just did clonezilla to copy the disk to a file as-is, the result is not a usable virtual disk.

Comment: I clonezilla to image, then clonezilla image to vdisk, I'm using proxmox as my hypervisor.

Comment: The only reason a Hypervisor would be unable to boot your Windows 7 VM is if it had UEFI boot enabled. Current versions of modern Hypervisors don’t support UEFI and Windows 7 together

Comment: I'm able to do a clean install of windows 7 in UEFI in this hypervisor

Comment: @unixnerd777 - So was the physical installation of Windows 7 installed in Legacy Mode or UEFI?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by running sysprep to OOBE, going through the OOBE and deleting the OOBE user. I was then able to re-image the source machine back to before I ran sysprep.